# about spring social xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-social

i wonder "#{request.userPrincipal.name}" in configuration blow. when I run my spring social project it always has error at "#{request.userPrincipal.name}", if I set a value such as "123" my project runs well. what's wrong and is there any other configuration instead of "#{request.userPrincipal.name}" ?

```
<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository" factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
    <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @Seong are you trying to populate the value of #{request.userPrincipal.name} using from props file, if yes then i think u should use ${request.userPrincipal.name}  , $ instead of #

Comment: yes I want to use ${request.userPrincipal.name}  but I don't know How to set a correct value! It always has error like this:   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 22): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on null

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Spring EL expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef), which means getting the user identity from the Http request. Once you apply your own User Management component, you can replace `#{request.userPrincipal.name}` with your own way.

Comment: How to make my own User Management component and replace #{request.userPrincipal.name} ???  if I want to use #{request.userPrincipal.name} how can I do?

Comment: @Seong You can use existing framework to implement User Management component, for instance, using Spring security. In the simplest form, you can bind the user identity as a http parameter, for instance, 'http://example.com?username=foo', so #{request.username} would equals foo.

Comment: but HttpServletRequest don't has getUsername() method. so SpEL can not get the value from request.username   -_-!

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it should be #{request.getParameter('username')}

Comment: thank you, but i have another idea that using a factory bean generate a userId and set it ^^ how do you think about this idea ?

Comment: @Seong Yeah, it's feasible. Have a try.